# summary of s3 objects created daily

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a process which will load all files to an S3 bucket. I subscribed(SNS) to the bucket which triggers an email for each file. However, my process is loading over a 10000 files everyday.

What is the best way to summarize and just have one email notification(at a certain time of the day) with total files uploaded. Also, send an email when no files are received by that time?

Comment: [S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory.html) can be scheduled update daily and you can use its detailed report.

Comment: I would definitely look into S3 Inventory as mentioned. If that doesn't work for your needs, I would have the notifications go to a Lambda function which updates a DynamoDB table. And then have another Lambda function run on a daily schedule, query DynamoDB, and send a summary.

Comment: **Side-note:** It can be difficult to manage a bucket that contains millions of objects. If you are receiving 10,000+ objects a day and you wish to keep the data, it might be advisable to combine data from smaller files into fewer, larger files.

Comment: Good Idea @MarkB. May be I can just count total objects loaded into the bucket at a certain time in Lambda and send a summary. counts are good enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do a list bucket operation daily, that would be wasteful on a large bucket, use the S3 inventory to generate the daily inventory then either compare against the previous day or use the timestamps in the CSV.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory.html

Answer (score 0):

You should **schedule a daily run of an AWS Lambda function** that will:

- **List the contents** of the S3 bucket
- **Count the number of objects** with a `LastModified` within the previous 24 hours
- **Send a notification** via Amazon SNS

If the bucket is receiving 10,000+ objects each day, it can take a considerable time to list the contents of the bucket. Make sure the Lambda function has a suitably high *timeout* since it can only list 1000 objects per API call.